# update directive from service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service

I would like my directive to be updated as soon as my model in the service get modified.

I can not achieve it yet:

service:

```
  function pickerService(){
      // picked elements
      // do something for the status
      this.pickList = [{'file':'imthefilename', 'status':'100', 'size':'20kB'},
                 {'file':'imthefilename2', 'status':'100', 'size':'20kB'},
                 {'file':'imthefilename3', 'status':'100', 'size':'20kB'}];
   }
   ...
   pickerService.prototype.test = function(){
       this.pickList.push({'test':'ya'});
   };
   ...
```

directive:

```
   ...    
   scope['pickList'] = pickerService.pickList;
   ...
```

I have a button which calls my service 'test' method.

If I click the button one time nothing happens. I expect to see:

```
[{'file':'imthefilename', 'status':'100', 'size':'20kB'},
 {'file':'imthefilename2', 'status':'100', 'size':'20kB'},
 {'file':'imthefilename3', 'status':'100', 'size':'20kB'},
 {'test':'ya'}
]
```

But instead I see the older values of my variable:

```
[{'file':'imthefilename', 'status':'100', 'size':'20kB'},
 {'file':'imthefilename2', 'status':'100', 'size':'20kB'},
 {'file':'imthefilename3', 'status':'100', 'size':'20kB'}
]
```

If I click the button a 2nd time, the view is updated. I see:

```
[{'file':'imthefilename', 'status':'100', 'size':'20kB'},
 {'file':'imthefilename2', 'status':'100', 'size':'20kB'},
 {'file':'imthefilename3', 'status':'100', 'size':'20kB'},
 {'test':'ya'}
]
```

instead of:

```
[{'file':'imthefilename', 'status':'100', 'size':'20kB'},
 {'file':'imthefilename2', 'status':'100', 'size':'20kB'},
 {'file':'imthefilename3', 'status':'100', 'size':'20kB'},
 {'test':'ya'},
 {'test':'ya'}
]
```

It seems like a timing issue, the view is updated only if I click another time on my view button.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Best,

Answer (score 0):

I don't think AngularJS works in that way, a service is a somewhat like a singleton which you access for information, the service itself does not broadcast to your controllers. So in your controller, you need to run your service, wait for the promise to finish and return data, then it will automatically update your view and directive. Think of it like this:

`// your service should be defined as a service, not as just a function
app.service('PickerService', [$http', function($http) {
    return {
        getFiles: function(){ 
            return $http.get('files.json');
        }
    }
}]);`

then in your controller do this:

`PickerService.getFiles().then(function(returnValues){
        $scope.myDirectiveData = returnValues.data;
    });`

and your directive, when bound to a scope variable will update automatically:

```
<my-directive data="myDirectiveData"></my-directive>
```